# Improving an underfit model with Catboost for regression problem

Tags: loss-functions, model-evaluation, fitting, catboost

I'm currently using `CatboostRegressor(iterations=500, random_seed=123, cat_features=['month_number', 'day_of_week', 'year'])` for developing a 1-year predictive model at a **daily** level. The predictor variables are time feature `date`, **categorical** features `A1 - A4` (e.g. `A1 = Group: 1/2/3/4, A2 = Class: Upper/middle/lower`) , and numerical features `A5 - A7` (e.g. `A5 = Price: 100/125.6/132.7, A6 = Age 25/30/31/57`). The response variable is a **continuous** variable (e.g. `revenue/rental price`)

My current model with `CatboostRegressor(iterations=500, random_seed=123)` with two initialized parameters `loss_function = MAE, eval_metric = 'MAE'` mostly underfits the actualized data although the final `MAPE` was around `10%-20%` (so, some overfits offsets the underfits). However, I am unsure how the `MAE` function described in the documentation of Catboost defines the weight `w_i` for each prediction error, as the `MAE` is the weighted average of all the prediction errors. In particular, what do they mean by saying *Use object/group weights to calculate metrics if the specified value is true* (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).  I am unable to find any examples on how these weights are set, because if the weights are equally weighted, the model would probably not under-fit?

What I have tried so far to improve the **under-fit** issue  is that I already used almost the *entire* *training* dataset to **train** the `CatboostRegressor(),` it is not a feasible option now to increase `training size.` The most potential option now is to increase the number of iterations from `500` to `1000`, although this alone did not help much.

**Question.** How do we customize the `loss_function` and `eval_metric` to cope with `underfit` issue? The tutorial provided for writing custom loss function is quite complicated that I couldn't follow, so any other tangible examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Even if it's long, I cannot understand your question. Boosted trees model need careful tuning of the many parameters. For instance, using a proper *combination* of learning rate and number of trees is essential. (More trees is not necessarily better.) Furthermore, using almost all data for training does not sound like a proper validation strategy. Why MAE? Why case weights? What is the aim of the model? What is the data structure?

Comment: @Michael M Apologize for confusing you. Data structure is mainly `pandas` dataframe. Good question on `MAE` (reason: `RMSE` does not help improve the underfit). The aim of the model is to predict a continuous variable (e.g. daily revenue, daily price) at a daily level for the entire year. I am not sure what you meant with case weights, but if you are talking about the weights of MAE in `CatboostRegressor()`, it is the *default* choice. Regarding the number of trees and learning rate, I have not yet tuned it (reason is simple, I prefer sticking with the default choice with black-box ML model).